# java.lang.RuntimeException: not supported: class org.spockframework.gentyref.CaptureTypeImpl

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, groovy, spock

Spock is being used to execute an integration test in a Spring Boot project (2.1.18.RELEASE). When I run with 1.3-groovy-2.5, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: not supported: class org.spockframework.gentyref.CaptureTypeImpl
    at org.spockframework.gentyref.GenericTypeReflector.erase(GenericTypeReflector.java:33)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.StaticMockMethod.getReturnType(StaticMockMethod.java:50)
    at org.spockframework.mock.EmptyOrDummyResponse.respond(EmptyOrDummyResponse.java:68)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.handle(MockController.java:50)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockInterceptor.intercept(JavaMockInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyInterceptorAdapter.interceptNonAbstract(ByteBuddyInterceptorAdapter.java:35)
    at com.foo.controller.ConversionsController.createConversionJob(ConversionsController.java:68)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 18 more
```

If I update Spock to a more recent version (eg. 2.1-groovy-2.5) I get this error:

```
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.junit.platform.engine.TestEngine: org.spockframework.runtime.SpockEngine Unable to get public no-arg constructor
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:733)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

I am using Java 11 and Maven 3.6.3. My pom.xml is rather long, so I've reduced it to some snippets that focus on versions and test dependencies:

```
        <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                <java.version>11</java.version>
                <bytebuddy.version>1.11.0</bytebuddy.version>
                <cglib.version>3.2.12</cglib.version>
                <gmavenplus.version>1.12.0</gmavenplus.version>
                <groovy.version>2.5.15</groovy.version>
                <objenesis.version>3.2</objenesis.version>
                <spock.version>1.3-groovy-2.5</spock.version>
                <maven.buildhelper.version>3.3.0</maven.buildhelper.version>
                <maven.jacoco.version>0.8.7</maven.jacoco.version>
                <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>
                <maven.failsafe.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.failsafe.version>
        </properties>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                        <exclusions>
                                <exclusion>
                                        <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                                </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- uncommented for 2.1-groovy-2.5 -->
                <!-- dependency>
                        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spock-junit4</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency> <!-- enables mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces) -->
                        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
                        <version>${bytebuddy.version}</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency> <!-- enables mocking of classes without default constructor (together with ByteBuddy or CGLIB) -->
                        <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
                        <version>${objenesis.version}</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                       <plugin>
                                <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn more about this plugin,
                                     visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>${gmavenplus.version}</version>
                                <executions>
                                        <execution>
                                                <goals>
                                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                                        <goal>compileTests</goal>
                                                </goals>
                                        </execution>
                                </executions>
                                <configuration>
                                        <targetBytecode>11</targetBytecode>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
```

Any help with troubleshooting this further is greatly appreciated. I modelled my pom.xml after the examples in the spock framework project:

- https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/pom.xml
- https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/spock-1.x/pom.xml

Comment: Do you understand the newer error message?

Comment: I am happy to move to a more recent version of Spock. This is a similar question without a clear answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68595956/org-spockframework-runtime-spockengine-unable-to-get-public-no-arg-constructor-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding `java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.junit.platform.engine.TestEngine: org.spockframework.runtime.SpockEngine Unable to get public no-arg constructor`

Spring Boot `2.1.18.RELEASE` is really old, it manages JUnit 5 to `5.3.2` while Spock 2.x requires >= `5.8`. You can try setting `<junit-jupiter.version>5.8.1</junit-jupiter.version>` if you can't upgrade Spring Boot to a more recent version.

As for the type reflection error, we can't say much since you didn't share any code. Only that `com.foo.controller.ConversionsController.createConversionJob(ConversionsController.java:68)` probably has some weird generics or is calling something that does.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upgrade the Spring Boot version at this time. I fiddled with excluding junit as a transient dependency and explicitly including a newer version of `junit-jupiter` but was not successful. I was able to figure out the issue thanks to you pointing out that the exception is a reflection error.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer from [Leonard Brünings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145769/leonard-br%c3%bcnings) as it pointed me in the right direction, but wanted to add more explanation as to cause of the problem.

The `java.lang.RuntimeException: not supported: class org.spockframework.gentyref.CaptureTypeImpl` is a reflection error that indicates a problem with a method being mocked.

> The exception points to the fact that it can't determine the correct response type of the stub method being called

I had a method like this:

```
public class Foo {

    public ResponseEntity<?> bar(Long id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In my test I did this:

```
setup:
Foo mockFoo = Stub()

given:
String id = '123'

and:
ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>('Hello World', HttpStatus.OK)

and:
mockFoo.bar(id) >> response

...
```

Because `id` was declared a `String` instead of a `Long`, the exception was thrown. However, when I changed it to a `Mock()` instead of a `Stub()` and also used a cardinality rule, then it became apparent that the mocked method was not being invoked with a more useful error message:

```
then:
mockFoo.bar(id) >> response
0 * _  // don't allow any other interaction
```

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is Too many invocations for:

0 * _  // don't allow any other interaction   (1 invocation)
```

Comment: There must be something more, e.g. generics or it would have returned an empty string for the unmatched invocation. The exception points to the fact that it can't determine the correct response type of the stub method being called.

Comment: Yes, it is a Spring Boot project being tested with the @WebMvcTest annotation, and the class under test is a Controller. The class being mocked does not make use of generics (but is annotated with @Service), and the method has a simple argument list. The mocked method returns ResponseEntity<?>, which is the generic you are referring to.

The example is for illustrative purposes.